# Stretch Dropdown of CSS Menu

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

Please see the menu screenshot
http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/2057/menukg.jpg

I am trying to recreate a menu using CSS. I got everything done except 1 thing. I can't stretch the drop down width to 100%.

I want the  drop down to stretch, just like the menu in fig 2(original)

Heres the code http://jsfiddle.net/LcXRe/

Comment: Show us the code or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: please provide the code. how can we create the whole code here to solve this issue. As you are saying you have created the code but stuck in expanding, so at least show the code so we can fix it.

Comment: @DjZia Prodigal - hey i m feeling glad to solve your problem. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one - Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/LcXRe/4/

Full view Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LcXRe/4/embedded/result/